# Unsub and Resub Observable in Activity

Tags: android, rx-java, android-lifecycle, rx-android

According to what i have studies and understood , RxLifecycle allows to unsubscribe , the observables if you attach `.compose(bindToLifecycle())` with it ,

But my question here is what will happen if we want to resubscribe the same observable without doing extra work ? , is it possible help me with your suggestion , and most Likely code examples if possible?

Comment: what do you mean by "resubscribe"? For example: if you make subscription in `onResume()` it will be subscribed when activity goes to this method and unsubscribed in `onPause()`. So in fact it will be resubscribed each time when activity goes from `Paused` state

Comment: i can't do that in onResume , that way it will subscribe two times , because i'm already doing in onCreate , and views will not be ready in onResume

Comment: So don't subscribe in `onCreat()`, only in `onResume()`. About "not ready view": `onCreate` is at the beginning of activity creating process and `onResume` is just before displaying. So in `onResume` activity is more "ready" than in `onCreate`

Comment: that's still not the point , main concern here is to automatically resubscribe that Observable we bound with the lifecycle, is it possible?

Comment: when exactly do you want to resubscribe it?

Comment: just after starting the app , means maybe onResume , or maybe after that , but manually doing so beat the purpose of `bindToLifeCycle`

Comment: So back to my first comment: just make `.compose(bindToLifeCycle).subscribe(...)` in onResume(). So it will be unsubscribed each time, when activity goes to `onPause()` and resubscribe when `onResume()`